# Boyd & Vandenberghe, Example 3.10 — Convexity of $X \mapsto \lambda_ {\max}(X)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-optimization, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to understand how the function $$f(X) = \lambda_ {\max}(X)$$ with domain $\mbox{dom}(f) = S^m$ is convex. [Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) say that $f(X)$ can be expressed as $$f(X) = \sup\left\{{y}^\top X y \mid \| y \|_2 = 1 \right\}$$ is convex. See attached image from the text.

[image: example 3.10]

I have reasoned as follows. Since X is a symmetric matrix, it has $m$ eigenvectors corresponding to $m$ eigenvalues, which form a basis for R<sup>m</sup>. Therefore, for any vector y with norm(y) =1 in R<sup>m</sup>, we can express $\\{y}^\intercal Xy$ as $\sum(\alpha_i*v_i)^\intercal X \sum(\alpha_i*v_i) $, where the $v_i$ are the corresponding eigenvectors. But then I get that
\begin{align}
\\{y}^\intercal Xy = \sum(\alpha_i*v_i)^\intercal X \sum(\alpha_i*v_i) = \sum(\alpha_i^2*\lambda_i)
\end{align}
And that doesn't allow me to conclude, as the text does, that
\begin{align}
\sup({y}^\intercal Xy ) = \lambda_\max (X)
\end{align}

Appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: [Listed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that $\|y\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2$. (Recall the $v_i$ form an orthonormal basis.)

Then check that the best choice of $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 \lambda_i$ is to let all of them be zero except for $\alpha_1^2=1$ (for $\lambda_1$ being the largest eigenvalue).

Comment: Ok, I see. But why would setting all alpha  =0 except alpha_1 = 1 be the best choice- any easy way to understand this? This is the stumbling block for me! Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you let $w_i = \alpha_i^2$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 1$, so $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \lambda_i$ is a weighted average of the $\lambda_i$, which you can show to always be between $\lambda_{\max}$ and $\lambda_{\min}$. @user2450223